# How to fix 404 nginx error on routers after letsencrypt installation

Tags: laravel, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, vesta

I'm setting up a new server running on vestaCP+NGINX+php-fpm and laravel backend , after installing letsencrypt , I'm encountering with 404 error on all of my routers except the main page . the laravel .env is ok and my nginx conf is as follows , also , another nginx conf file has been created for ssl by the control panel . The site works without any problem on http protocol .

```
server {
    listen      xx.xxx.xxx.xx:443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;


    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;

    location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;

        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}

error_page  403 /error/404.html;
error_page  404 /error/404.html;
error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/document_errors/;
}

location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}
location /vstats/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/stats/;
    include /home/admin/conf/web/example.com.auth*;
}

include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

include     /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.example.com.conf*;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

I am not a Nginx expert, but it seems to me that all `location` directives should be inside the `server` directive, and currently they aren't. Also you have nested `location` directives that I think they aren't necessary...

Start by trying to fix that with this:

```
server {
    listen      xx.xxx.xxx.xx:443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;


    ssl         on;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/
        #try_files $uri =404;
        #try index.php =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/stats/;
        include /home/admin/conf/web/example.com.auth*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.example.com.conf*;
}
```

> **NOTE**: This isn't tested, thus try it in development and if you fix any syntax in the file or an error please let me know so that I can update the answer. If you can't fix please let us know what went wrong so that we can try further help.

## Possible Improvement

Once you use Laravel you can try to follow the Nginx configuration [Php Docker Stack](https://gitlab.com/exadra37-docker/php/docker-stack/blob/41dc4d30efba39e1a33c4579c1485d47e2d989c3/src/docker/http/nginx/build/conf.d/default.conf) that works straight out of the box with Laravel.

The bit you need to copy to replace the current one in your Nginx conf `server{}` directive is this one:

```
    # In Laravel we only need serve index.php
    location @proxyphp {
        rewrite (.*) /index.php;
    }

    # serving only index.php increases the security in your application. 
    location ~ /index\.php$ {
        # https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/
        #try_files $uri =404;
        #try index.php =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    # Deny access to all php files that are not index.php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
```

#### The Security Improvments

In Laravel we only need to serve index.php and doing it so increases the security in your application, once it only have 1 public entry point, instead of being accessible by any `*.php` in the `public` folder of Laravel app.

Comment: sorry but the solution did not work for me , I got "nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream" error

Comment: did you replaced the `xxx.xxx:443` for your IP and updated the `example.com` to your own domain? I see now that I forgot to update the `fastcgi_pass` in my answer to reflect the one used by you... I will update ti.

Comment: sure , I have done every thing , but nothing changed

Comment: Sorry to hear that... did you applied the last changes I made after my last comment. I changed from `fastcgi_pass php:9000;` to `fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9001;`.